# Dynamic initialization in C++ when you don't control main

Tags: c++, c++14

I have a rather idiosyncratic C++14 initialization issue. I'm linking against a C library which provides `main()`. That library makes use of a global array that I'm meant to define, something like this:

```c
extern int array[];

int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; array[i] != -1; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
}
```

The expected use is to initialize the array, e.g. `int array[] = {1, 2, 3, -1}`. But I want to be able to dynamically initialize it. I'm using C++14, so my thought was to create a global object with a constructor that writes to the array, like this:

```cpp
int array[2];

struct Init {
    Init() {
        array[0] = 1;
        array[1] = -1;
    }
}

Init init;
```

But the C++14 standard says this:

> It is implementation-defined whether the dynamic initialization of a non-local variable with static storage duration is done before the first statement of main. If the initialization is deferred to some point in time after the first statement of main, it shall occur before the first odr-use (3.2) of any function or variable defined in the same translation unit as the variable to be initialized.

Am I reading this correctly that it's possible that when `main()` runs, my object won't yet have been constructed, meaning that my array won't be initialized (or rather, will be default  initialized, not by my class)?

If so, is there any way around this?  I have no control over the library which provides `main()`. Am I out of luck in wanting to set the array's value at startup time, before `main()` runs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> it shall occur before the first odr-use (3.2) of ***any function or variable*** defined in the same translation unit

Emphasis "any function or variable". The "variable" part includes, of course, the global variable in question.

In other words, the initialization is guaranteed to occur before odr-use of the variable. Problem solved.

So, as soon as anything in your C++ program sneezes in the direction of "any function or variable" in the translation unit where the global array is defined, they will materialize into existence.

You are guaranteed before the `array` is odr-used, the initialized of `init` takes place, since it's in the same translation unit, and that will take care of whipping `array` into shape, before it gets odr-used.

Comment: And I quoted the exact part of the standard that answered my question.  Thank you for pointing that out so succinctly!

Comment: What about the *in the same translation unit as the variable to be initialized* part? `main()` is not in the same TU as the array so couldn't the loop be entered before it's values were initialized in `init`s initialization?

Comment: @NathanOliver I agreed with you initially and posted a comment to that effect, but then I re-read yet again: "initialization … shall occur before the first odr-use of any … variable defined in the same translation unit as the variable to be initialized." As Sam noted, the first odr-use of "array" is in main, but array is _defined_ in my own code.  The _use_ doesn't have to be in the same translation unit, just the definition.

Comment: Right. As long as both `init` and `array` are in the same translation unit, any odr-use of `array` will pull the cord and open the parachute, @NathanOliver.

Comment: But can't main run before `init` is initialized meaning `array` has not been initialized?

Comment: Yes it can run, @NathanOliver but as soon as something odr-uses `array` the parachute opens. All this is about is letting implementations some flexibility in implementing the static initialization order fiasco. All of that can happen before `main()`, or some of it can get postponed until after `main()` gets invoked, but before anything odr-uses anything in the translation unit.